# SpringBoot - Using the oAuth2 clientId combined with user credentials for authentication purposes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm looking to add SSO functionality between 4 or 5 independent applications / clients.

We will store users centrally and the datamodel we are adopting is as follows:

user <-->  user_clients <--> client

so a user could be registered on anything between 1 to 'many' clients.

Its easy enough to redirect requests to the central auth service and grant access based on the correct username / password credentials however I'm unable to restrict access based on whether the user is registered on a particular client application.

Based on other stackoverflow questions and answers I've looked at extending the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter however I'm unable to access the oAuth clientId which can be used to validate if the user is registered to that application, e.g.

```
private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String username = obtainUsername(request);
    String password = obtainPassword(request);
    String clientId = obtainClientId(request); // ?? how do we get this from the request - implemented method returns null

    if (username == null) {
        username = "";
    }
    if (password == null) {
        password = "";
    }
    if (clientId == null) {
        clientId = "";
    }

    String userClient = String.format("%s%s%s", username.trim(), 
        String.valueOf(Character.LINE_SEPARATOR), clientId);
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userClient, password);        
}

private  String obtainClientId(HttpServletRequest request){
    
    final String authorizationHeaderValue = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    final String base64AuthorizationHeader = Optional.ofNullable(authorizationHeaderValue)
            .map(headerValue->headerValue.substring("Basic ".length())).orElse("");

    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(base64AuthorizationHeader)){
        String decodedAuthorizationHeader = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64AuthorizationHeader), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        return decodedAuthorizationHeader.split(":")[0];
    }

    return "";
}
```

So in summary I'm wishing to obtain the oAuth client id and use it during the request cycle.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement multiple auth providers:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers